# Reading bytes and characters off BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, android

I am currently writing a simple multipart/form-data type parser.

I have a BufferedInputStream as an input. multipart/form-data has both raw byte data and character data.

In some cases, I need to read characters (User defined encoding), and some case i need to read raw bytes. Is there any easy way to do this short of making a custom reader with character and byte support?

Limitations:
Buffers cannot be more than 16k in size.

Comment: What charset are the characters in?

Comment: @Jeffrey User defined, defaults to latin-1.

Comment: Do you have control over the code that is generating the stream of bytes and characters?

Comment: @Jeffrey The stream of bytes is from a web browser. So, the answer is no.

Comment: Will you know ahead of time what charset the characters will be in?

Comment: @Jeffrey Yes, also there is always known characters delimiting raw byte data.